# Why does a larger batch size not speed up evaluation time on Huggingface significantly?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, huggingface-datasets

I'm trying to evaluate my model on the Squad dataset:

```
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = AutoModelForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained(model_name).to(device)
model.eval() # eval mode

# trainer arguments
args = TrainingArguments(output_dir = 'tmp', per_device_eval_batch_size=256)
# trainer
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=args,
    tokenizer=tokenizer)

with torch.no_grad():
    # load dataset
    squad = load_dataset('squad') 
    squad_validation = squad['validation']
    # preprocess
    original_validation_dataset = squad_validation.map(preprocess_validation_examples,batched=True,remove_columns=squad_validation.column_names)
    trainer_output = trainer.predict(original_validation_dataset)
```

However, it seems like it doesn't matter if my `per_device_eval_batch_size` is 1,8,16,256, or 512, it always results in about 1 min of evaluation time. Batch of size 1 results in 1 min and 32 sec, batch of size 8 results in 1 min and 16 sec, batch of size 512 results in 1 min and 6 sec.

I'd expect the batch size to matter much more than a few seconds different so I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong. Loading the model takes 4.3 seconds, and with a batch size of 1024 I run of GPU memory.

Comment: So it is getting faster, just not as you expected? Maybe your expectation is wrong.

Comment: Maybe. But there's a very big difference between a batch of size 8 and a batch of size 512, and the time difference is about 10 seconds. Just wanted to make sure I'm not missing anything because this is quite odd

Comment: It just means that the bottleneck is probably not compute.